# Method Delegation to Self

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I want to use Byte-Buddy to generate a class that delegates interface methods to a method inherited from a superclass.

The two code snippets below do this:

```
Class<? extends Object> clazz = new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(serviceSuperClass)
    .name(className) 
    .implement(serviceInterface)
    .defineField(generalInterceptor, GrandFatherProxy.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
    .method(isDeclaredBy(serviceInterface))
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.toField(generalInterceptor))
    .make ()
    .load(classLoader)
    .getLoaded();
```

In this case GrandFatherProxy.class is a super class of the given serviceSuperClass, and thus of clazz.

Once I have used Reflection to generate an instance of clazz, I can then set the field generalInterceptor with the instance:

```
Field field = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(generalInterceptor);
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(instance, instance);  // set field on instance to contain instance!
```

This works: Clazz now delegates to self: all the interface methods are intercepted by the `@RuntimeType intercept()` method clazz inherits from GrandFatherProxy.class.

However it would be even more elegant if I could explicitly instruct Byte-Buddy to self-delegate.

e.g. something like:

```
Class<? extends Object> clazz = new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(serviceSuperClass)
    .name(className) 
    .implement(serviceInterface)
    .method(isDeclaredBy(serviceInterface))
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.toSelf())
    .make ()
    .load(classLoader)
    .getLoaded();
```

Where `toSelf()` is my pseudo code to instruct Byte-Buddy that the generated class should delegate to itself.

Have I missed a way to do this? Or would it require a change to Byte-Buddy?

Answer (score 0):

You can trick your way around it by defining a private method that returns `this` and then use `MethodDelegation.toMethodReturnOf` on this method. To add this functionality, it would require a change to the library.

Comment: While such a clever trick may work, it probably won't improve the readability of the Byte-Buddy configuration. My current approach (defining a field + intercepting Methods to that field + setting field with dynamic instance via Reflection is still reasonably readable). I kind of guessed that an explicit toSelf() (or similar construct) would require a library change (but one that is nice-to-have). I will open a change request on your Github.